# The "Working with bugs" option has gone missing within my "Configure team settings" option

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps...

The "Working with bugs" option has gone missing within my "Configure team settings" option.

This is after I selected the "Bugs are not managed on backlogs and boards" option and saved.

How do I get the "Working with bugs" option back so I can see these on my boards again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be available at the following link:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_settings/work-team
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response. Worked a treat!